# Datascrape twitter into csv (tweeepy, python). How to append if file already exists:

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, tweepy

I have the following code:

```
import tweepy #https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
import csv
import random

#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

twitname = raw_input("Enter desired twitter account from which a tweet will be selected to act as inspiration for the poem: ")




def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
    #Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with this method

    #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    #initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []  

    #make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    #save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    #keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)

        #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)

        #save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))

    #transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv 
    outtweets = [[tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]

    #write the csv  
    with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["text"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)

    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pass in the username of the account you want to download
    get_all_tweets(twitname)




spamReader = csv.reader(open(twitname + '_tweets.csv', 'r'))

twitterinsp = sum([i for i in spamReader],[]) #To flatten the list
print(random.choice(twitterinsp))
```

Currently it scrapes the most recent tweets, stores them in a csv file, and then displays a random entry. What I'm trying to do is have it so if the csv file already exists it appends new tweets to the already existing csv. Is this possible/does anyone have any ideas? If this isn't possible, does anyone know how I would write the if else function here: if file exists, print random entry, else scrape, store, and then print random entry. Any hellp is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of 'wb' you use 'ab'

```
with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'ab') as f:
```

file modes: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation

```
Mode    Description
'r' Open a file for reading. (default)
'w' Open a file for writing. Creates a new file if it does not exist or truncates the file if it exists.
'x' Open a file for exclusive creation. If the file already exists, the operation fails.
'a' Open for appending at the end of the file without truncating it. Creates a new file if it does not exist.
't' Open in text mode. (default)
'b' Open in binary mode.
'+' Open a file for updating (reading and writing)
```

Comment: what is the benefit of writing to binary here?

Comment: I kept it there because the original code had it in binary.  I imagine binary is quicker to read/write, and has smaller file size.  But don't quote me on that.

Comment: Nice and easy, thanks! Slightly different but related question: Do you know if there is a way to append only new data?

Comment: not familiar with the twitter API, but if you retrieve the tweets, create a pandas dataframe with them and the old tweets, you can drop all repeats based on a given index `df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'keyColumns')`